# Laminate Floor, existing is 8mm, installing 12 mm next to it, How should I transition?

Tags: laminate, transition

So the current laminate floor is 8mm, we are removing the carpet and installing 12mm right next to it.  Currently there is standard T molding with the blunt edge adapter strip on one side.  I would like to reuse the T molding and just remove the   under strip.  But I worry that this 4 mm different will cause issues.  What would you recommend?  Is there something out there designed for this?  I am having trouble finding this exact situation.
Thanks

Comment: What's the height of the existing T molding? Will it come out flush with the new floor?

Comment: It looks like it was made for the 8 mm flooring.  When it is inserted into the metal track it is full engaged.

Comment: That didn't answer my question.

Comment: Sorry, new to this.  It looks like it is a Pergo 4-in-1 laminate moulding.  http://www.pergoonline.com/4-in-1-laminate-molding-36053/

Comment: It is design to transition for flooring from 8mm to 12mm, but I worry that there will be a gap on the side that is 8mm...

Comment: What I'm wondering is whether you can remove the side of the existing T facing the new floor, install the new floor, then install a new T spanning from the new floor to the old T. Hence the question about height.

Comment: I see, that might work.  I may need to use a scrap and see how it lays to determine the best route.  That does make some sense.